# Get item id (file) from list by name with JSOM

Tags: javascript, csom, jsom

How to get ID from specific item by name like (file.doc)

Code bellow get item by ID :

```
var itemId = 18; // real id

      var listTitle = "Documents"; // the list title

      var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      var spWeb = ctx.get_web();

      var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);

      var item = list.getItemById(itemId);

      ctx.load(spWeb);
      ctx.load(item);
```

Thank you for help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to query the `FileLeafRef` hidden internal column by forming a CAML query as below.

Do try and modify the below sample code:

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list  = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Documents');
var fileName = "file.doc";  
var collListItem;
var oListItem;

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml(
                      "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query>" +
                      "<Where>" +
                         "<Eq><FieldRef Name=\"FileLeafRef\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">" + fileName + "</Value></Eq>" +
                      "</Where>" +
                      "</Query></View>");
collListItem = list.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while(listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {    
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        console.log(oListItem.get_id());
    }
},function(sender, args){
    console.log("something went wrong");
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
});
```